# Layout design in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

Here is the scenario, there are tables on our report (rdlc) that render data on screen we call them sections, now based on a condition we hide these sections and hence a gap is created between them, is there any control available or layout option that can be adopted to overcome this problem where I cannot see any gap between two sections, and layout stay consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the tables in **Rectangle** objects, then set the visibility for the Rectangles, not the tables themselves.

If the Rectangle is slightly longer than the tables, and all the Rectangles are immediately adjacent, there will be whitespace in the Rectangles which will disappear when the Rectangles are hidden.

This way you will have the same behaviour but better control of the gaps that were created when you just hide individual items.

Comment: It helped me but still there are gaps though much less between the rectangles even when they are immediately adjacent?